# C function for converting arbitrary structure from Host to Network byte order?

Tags: c, endianness

I have created a function `my_hton()` to convert data in host byte order to network byte order. It converts object of any arbitrary structure. If it is correct, why does C has functions like `htons()` and `htonl()` which converts only 2 and 4 bytes respectively, instead of having one function for all data types, or am I missing something?

```
void my_hton(char *buffer, char *p, size_t i){
    if( is_little_endian() ){
        while(i > 0){
            *buffer = p[i-1];
            buffer++;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

struct demo{
    int a;
    char b;
    char str[100];
    float f;
    double d;
    int *ptr;
};

int main() {
    char buffer[10000] = "";
    struct demo object;

    /*
    * object initialization
    */

    my_hton(buffer, (char*) &object, sizeof(object));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't provide introspection into data structures at function level, so this had to be a c primitive, which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: No, it is not correct.

Comment: A better question is __why__ would you want to convert the endian ness of an entire structure? It makes sense to change the endian ness of individual integer type fields, but that needs the information about the fields and hence you cannot a generic function.

Comment: Let apart aspects like padding, types don't have necessarily uniform endianess. Encoding is also not guaranteed. Your approach is broken by design, define a clean and erchitecture-independent exchange format. The write marshalling functions for types and then for each `struct`.

Comment: @V.d: How many different `struct` type-s do you have? *What is the concrete application*? How much data volume do you have (megabytes or petabytes)? What are the latency and bandwidth constraints? Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

What you have done in your code is flipped the entire structure byte wise, which would cause your individual members to be garbled.

A better question is why would you want to convert the endian ness of an entire structure?

It makes sense to change the endian ness of individual integer type fields, but that needs the information about the fields and hence you cannot have a generic function.

On the other hand if your structure has fixed size elements with equal padding, then you can write a generic function which can convert the endian-ness of each field. But I believe most structs made for network are packed and such cases would be very rare.

Comment: "But I believe most structs made for network are packed and such cases would be very rare." - That's a bad assumption. On most systems such packed `struct`s require additional code to access larger types which are misaligned in smaller portions and assemble the part to the actual type in registers. Such architectures include most RISC like ARM, MIPS, MSP430, etc. If the data is read more than once, this is a lot slower than properly marshalling once on send/receive. Additionally, there is no guarantee a byte has 8 bits (althouh this is a minor aspect on modern CPUs - but not on DSPs).

Comment: @Olaf even though the system has very strict alignment requirement, the bytes actual bytes transmitted would be packed (with packing and unpacking routines on either sides). So that the same bytes can be used on systems with different specifications and implementations. But yes, like you said if there is an application which a structure like you suggested, the user can write a generic `hton`.

Comment: It is 1) A performance problem using the `struct`. This is a major issue e.g. for embedded systems. 2) you forget about other aspects, e.g. encoding of signed integers or floats, etc. 3) Padding is an extension, it is not standard C.

Comment: @Olaf totally agree. It is just safe to assume that a design that requires such a function is a wrong (or bad) design,

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in general (because structure fields have [padding and alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) in addition of endianness for scalars), notably because C has no [type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) or [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) facilities. Also, it is unclear what should be done for pointers or unions or [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) in *general*.

**Read more about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).**

You might consider customizing some C compiler (e.g. extending GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or your own plugin) to assist you in that serialization task. I don't think it is worth the effort.

However, some frameworks are adding such facilities. Look for examples into [GTK Gobject introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection). Also look into C code generators like 
[RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). Consider binary formats like [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), [SMILE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile_(data_interchange_format)), [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One), etc.

In many cases, it is more convenient (even if slightly slower, but the bottleneck is often the network or the disk, not the CPU, so you won't even notice in most cases) to use some textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), XML, .... because [text protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) are very common and much easier to debug. You'll find many libraries to help you using these formats.